# Adding widgets dynamically in bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I want to add filters dynamically in bokeh, i.e. every time a button is pressed, a new filter is appended. However, the layout gets broken after a new widgets are added: new ones get written over old ones instead of the layout being recomputed. Code example

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def add_select():
    feature = Select(value='feat', options=["a"])
    dynamic_col.children.append(feature)

b1 = Button(label="Add condition", button_type="success")
b1.on_click(add_select)

b2 = Button(label="Apply", button_type="success")

dynamic_col = column()
curdoc().add_root(column(b1, dynamic_col, b2))
```

Layout before clicking "Add" button

[image: Layout before clicking "Add" button]

Layout after Select widget gets added

[image: Layout after Select widget gets added]

Comment: With recent versions of Bokeh (e.g. 2.2.1) the original code node works correctly as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a single list to handle all your widgets ?

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc

def add_select():
    feature = Select(value='feat', options=["a"])
    dynamic_col.children.insert(-1, feature)

b1 = Button(label="Add condition", button_type="success")
b1.on_click(add_select)

b2 = Button(label="Apply", button_type="success")

dynamic_col = column(b1, b2)
curdoc().add_root(dynamic_col)
```

I "insert" instead of "append" the widget to let the 2nd button at the end of the list

I got this result :

[image: result]

Comment: FYI with recent versions of Bokeh (e.g. 2.2.1) the original code node works correctly as-is.