# How to change the layout dynamically? How to add and remove layout objects properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, layout, bokeh

I want to build an app with many plots. It will have some tabs, and one gridplot within the tabs with some plots. In addition, I need to update the plots layout dynamically when the server is running.

- Remove or add some plots
- Remove or add some tabs

I have read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/P2WPJ9an7IQ), where Bryan (@bigreddot) says:

> The most well-used and understood (as well as more efficient) method is to create your plots once, up front, then update only their data when they need to change.
>
> Bokeh's layout capability is ambitious and complicated. It works well in a number of situations but I can easily believe there are update bugs that might be exposed when replacing complicated composite models like entire plots deep in a nested layout.

I have written the following example where I update the layout in four different ways:

1. Replacing the old plot by the children attribute on the layout object.
2. Replacing the layout with `curdoc()`
3. Replacing the plot using `remove()` and `append()`
4. Inserting a new plot using `insert()`

```py
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure

# ------------------- PLOT 1 --------------------------- #

plot_1 = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 3, 2, 1]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot_1.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='green',
)

# ------------------- PLOT 2 --------------------------- #

plot_2 = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
)

plot_2.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='red',
)

# ------------------- PLOT 3 --------------------------- #

plot_3 = figure(
    width=400,
    height=400,
)

plot_3.circle(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    source=source,
    radius=0.5,
    fill_alpha=0.6,
    fill_color='yellow',
)

# ------------------- BUTTONS --------------------------- #

def replace_by_children_attr():
    column_1.children = buttons + [plot_2]

def replace_by_curdoc():
    column_2 = column(buttons + [plot_2])

    curdoc().clear()
    curdoc().add_root(column_2)

def replace_by_remove_append():
    column_1.children.remove(plot_1)
    column_1.children.append(plot_2)

def insert_plot():
    column_1.children.insert(2, plot_3)

button_1 = Button(label="Replace plot by children attribute", button_type="success")
button_1.on_click(replace_by_children_attr)

button_2 = Button(label="Replace plot by curdoc", button_type="success")
button_2.on_click(replace_by_curdoc)

button_3 = Button(label="Replace plot remove-append", button_type="success")
button_3.on_click(replace_by_remove_append)

button_4 = Button(label="Insert plot", button_type="success")
button_4.on_click(insert_plot)

# ------------------- LAYOUT --------------------------- #

buttons = [button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4]
column_1 = column(buttons + [plot_1])

curdoc().add_root(column_1)

I realized that if I press the button "Replace plot by children attribute" the layout changes a little. But when I press "Replace plot by curdoc" the layout is not changed:
```

- So, which of these options is the best solution?
- Any of these solutions are going to give me problems? I know at least the first option is going to give me problems for sure

> **Note:** Actually, what I want to avoid is to restart the bokeh server to rebuild the layout because it takes a while. And I need to do it very often.
>
> **Note 2:** Bokeh version 0.12.14

Comment: If I had to do something like dynamic layout, I will look toward [bokeh.models api](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/7/5/idiomatic_bokeh/). You can easily add and remove glyphs from plot renderers (which is a list), I imagine you can do same with document/layout..

Comment: @louc Sure, I can use `append` as well instead of reassigning the layout to the complete list. But the problem is what I have written in my question: "It works well in a number of situations" (as Bryan says). I want to build a complex layout, so I was wondering if I do `curdoc().clear()` and `curdoc().add_root(new_layout)` would solve the problem. Moreover I can read on your link "Additive development, not subtractive or mutative", what I need to do is substractive or mutative.

Comment: If you can .append() , you can .remove() . I do so to add and remove glyph in a plot, legend ... The thing with the bokeh.models api is that you can keep in variable/list/dict the instance of object, so it is easy to remove them after. From what I have tested, update is rather smart and is done automatically

Comment: @louc OK, I have updated my question with your suggestion. So, can you guarantee that `append()` and `remove()` works well even if the layout is too complex? Could I also use `insert()` to avoid the limitation of appending elements always to the end of the list?

Comment: insert() will also work, I tested it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820780/adding-widgets-dynamically-in-bokeh/47876820#47876820). But I honestly don't know if it will work with very complex layout, I don't see why it couldn't work...

Comment: OK, thank you for your time. I will let you know if something goes wrong

Comment: Hi, i create plot through components(). So i include div and script into my html file. How is it possible to use on client side with JS, change one plot on another plot?

Comment: @VolArt I don´t really know, I am trying to program as much as possible within python