# How to trigger the rendering of a bokeh plot programatically?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, jinja2, bokeh

I have a lot of plots on my page and I don't want them to fire all on page load, but trigger them as the user scrolls down, or after a while.

I use the components module, so I'm unsure where to put a `setTimeout` or something like that.

in Django view I have:

```
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import components
script, div = components(plot.make_box_plot(), CDN)
```

and then in tag:

```
{% if div %}
  {{ div | safe }}
{% endif %}
{% if script %}
  {{ script | safe }}
{% endif %}
```

Does bokeh have some api for this?

This doesn't work as I get a js syntax error:

```
<script>
   window.plot_script = {{ script }}; // and then use it in a js file inside setTimeout
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at my question. Maybe it is useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566181/how-to-change-the-layout-dynamically-how-to-add-and-remove-layout-objects-prope You can update the layout appending or removing items from the children attribute (but this is on python side)